# Can I use SQL query in Freemarker template?

Tags: freemarker

I have a Freemarker template where I can get data from entity:

```
${Recipient.inventory.id}
${Recipient.inventory.name}
${Recipient.inventory.makeid}
${Recipient.inventory.modelid}
```

Is it possible to get data from a related table? Possibly with SQL statement?
After doing some research it looks like I might be able to use something called active:freemarker, but there doesn't seem to be any examples online how to use this.

Comment: IMO Freemarker should be as dumb a view as possible; get your data in  your Java code and expose it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker templates just see whatever you expose to them through the data-model. If for example you are using JPA and you keep the transaction going while the template is generated, you could traverse the database through the entity beans, if you add those beans to the data model. Issuing SQL directly from a template is hardly ever advisable. The point of FreeMarker is to provide you a layer where you deal with the presentation issues only.